Why arent the users that vote to reopen displayed in the same manner as users who vote to close
When a question is closed, users at a certain reputation level can see which users voted to close and the reason for closure. These statistics have been used as evidence
https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6082/67687
The same is NOT true when a question is reopened. The question returns to a pristine state as if nothing happened. I have NO idea who voted to reopen or the reasons that invalidated the closure.
Doesn't seem equitable.
This is in the "text box" for closed questions:

Modified today Viewed 412 times 2
Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently
accepting answers. Add details and clarify the problem being solved.
This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question.
Closed yesterday by Lowri, mudskipper, David Gudeman, Jo Wehler, Mark
Andrews.
This post was edited and submitted for review yesterday.
(List of close voters is only viewable by users with the close/reopen
votes privilege)


This appears to be a property of the way StackExchange is set up. It is not something that the moderators of the Philosophy site can do anything about.

Typically, all close and reopen voters are shown in the timeline of a post. It's not necessary to show reopen voters directly below the post, because a reopened post is simply an open post, nothing special about it. Please refer to the timeline (clock symbol left of posts) for all such details.

While I don't know how this works in general, for this question at least, I am able to see the reopen votes in the edit history:

As for the "cabal" talk, I would like it observed that I'm implicated in both the Cabal Of Biased Hateful Closers and the Cabal of Rule-Flouting Reopeners, and so maybe it's not as 'cabal'-y as people seem to think.

There is an extra "text box" that states why the question is closed and who closed it. When the question is reopened there is no "text box" that states why the question was reopened and who reopened it. There should be symmetry in the open/close process.

@IdiosyncraticSoul This bit is just speculation--ultimately it's a question that would have to be asked to staff. However, in general, I think the "closed" message is seen as a bit of a "stain" on a question. When a question is reopened, I think it makes sense to present it not as a "tainted" question with a warning in front of it, but just an ordinary question that may be read, upvoted and answered. So I suspect that's why the box doesn't remain.

it seems that 5 votes to reopen are "better"  than 5 votes to close. A different set of standards.

@IdiosyncraticSoul I guess I'm not sure I'd call them "better". If close -> reopen didn't "reset" the question back to the initial "good standing", wouldn't that make close votes more powerful than reopen votes, since all the reopen votes in the world could never remove the blaring "this question was closed and reopened" box at the top of the question?

Your own language indicates a slight bias: Votes to close "taint" or "stain"  the question and votes to reopen "clean" the question. I vote to close to identify a problem. I vote to reopen when the problem is solved or the reversal of a close vote is adequately explained.

@IdiosyncraticSoul The language choice was maybe a bit silly. Again, I agree w/ you regarding the purpose of close votes: I cast close votes regularly and I do it out of the hopes that the question may be improved and get better answers, not out of disgust or something. -- My concern is more... when the problem is solved, I don't think there should be anything atop a question saying "this question used to have a problem with it." Once the problem is solved, there's no reason to leave a "there was a problem here" billboard up on the question.

I see nothing wrong with full disclosure or no disclosure but half-disclosure bothers me.

It's like hiding the fact that your car was damaged by not disclosing the repair.

I don't agree, but I'm willing to hear what other people think... I guess next steps for you would be: 1. it's a question for mods (and maybe staff) whether a lingering banner is even possible 2. If that IS possible, a question of whether other people would actually like a lingering banner. (this question is, I think, about whether it's possible to see who reopened a question, and now we know it is)

I have removed my references to "cabal". I meant it "tongue in cheek" but it muddies the water.

The default state is a question being open. If a question remains open after 5 close and open votes, it only makes sense to stick to the default without displaying a closed tag. What’s your reasoning behind changing this?

@Syed Why not change the state to reopen and provide the same information as vote to close.

@IdiosyncraticSoul When a question is closed, it means something should and can be done about the current state of the question. Therefore, this possibility and possible ways to amend are highlighted. That's not the case for reopened questions. Also, this is a question for Meta.SE.

@PhilipKlöcking I'm satisfied and ready to move on.
